# FileStream keeps saying that the file is busy while it's not opened by any application at all

Tags: c#, filestream

I am trying to create a program that writes some kind of data to a file in C#. when I tried running the code, the console said that the file is busy even though I am not opening it at all.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace databaseProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Functions F = new Functions();

            string studentID;
            string studentName;
            string subjectA;
            string subjectB;


            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's ID.");
            studentID = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's name.");
            studentName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's score for subject A");
            subjectA = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the student's score for subject B");
            subjectB = Console.ReadLine();

            Functions.saveFile(studentID, studentName, subjectA, subjectB);
        }
    }

    public class Functions
    {


        public static void saveFile(string studentID, string studentName, string subjectA, string subjectB)
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream("DATA.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

            Console.WriteLine(studentID);
            Console.WriteLine(studentName);
            Console.WriteLine(subjectA);
            Console.WriteLine(subjectB);

            File.AppendAllText("DATA.txt", studentID + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText("DATA.txt", studentName + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText("DATA.txt", subjectA + Environment.NewLine);
            File.AppendAllText("DATA.txt", subjectB + Environment.NewLine);

            writer.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

the console will write this instead

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\codes\C#\databaseProjectCSlash\databaseProjectCSlash\bin\Debug\net6.0\DATA.txt' because it is being used by another process.
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.IO.File.AppendAllText(String path, String contents)
   at databaseProject.Functions.saveFile(String studentID, String studentName, String subjectA, String subjectB) in C:\Users\User\Documents\codes\C#\databaseProjectCSlash\databaseProjectCSlash\Program.cs:line 52
   at databaseProject.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Documents\codes\C#\databaseProjectCSlash\databaseProjectCSlash\Program.cs:line 34
```

after sending that message, the file would be wiped out of any data.

Thank you for your help, I really appreciate that.

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly suggest: a) following .NET naming conventions; b) declaring local variables at the point of first use; c) avoiding creating a class called `Functions` - just put the method directly in `Program`, or create a class with a more meaningful name.

Comment: "because it is being used by another process" is the worst part of that exception message because (as here) so often the guilty party is *the same process*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your process is conflicting *with itself*.

You're opening it here (in a way that would be simpler with `File.CreateText`, by the way) - but never actually using the writer you've created:

```cs
FileStream stream = new FileStream("DATA.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
```

... then you're *separately* trying to append to it here, even though `stream` is already open:

```cs
File.AppendAllText("DATA.txt", studentID + Environment.NewLine);
```

Pick *one* way of writing to the file, and stick to it. Personally, I'd suggest creating a `List<string>` or an array for all the lines you want to write, and just call `File.WriteAllLines` once, but you *could* continue to use either the writer approach or the `File.AppendAllText` approach... just not together like this.

Here's a simpler implementation of your `saveFile` method (renamed to follow normal naming conventions):

```cs
public static void SaveFile(string studentId, string studentName, string subjectA, string subjectB)
{
    var lines = new[] { studentId, studentName, subjectA, subjectB };
    // (Write the lines to the console here if you want.)
    File.WriteAllLines("DATA.txt", lines);
}
```

If you want to append data instead of recreating the file, just use `File.AppendAllLines` instead.